# Android Volley Questions

Tags: android, android-volley, synchronous

I'm new to android so bear with me here. I just started implementing `Volley` into my app after the latest android update which deprecated a lot of HTTP methods(When I updated the android OS in android studio the objects that are deprecated have a slash through them).

So I'm starting to implement `Volley` like I said and it's not complicated; I just want to be able to put all my networking code in one file. The issue with this is that the `onResult` method should call some UI updates once it finished. So now I have all my networking code in the activity that the code needs to be called in.

So I'm wondering what's the best way to do this. I thought about using the event, but to create a notification once the onResult method has been hit. Or maybe I can pass a weak reference of the activity into the networking class (but I don't want the code to be coupled so I don't wanna go this route).

So anyone has any ideas how to do this? Also how would I go about making synchronous calls in `Volley`?(I see I can just call the next function in the `onResult()` method and this will execute the methods one after another but I just want to know if it's possible to make synchronous calls in `Volley`)

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: I want to place all my networking calls in one class. I dont want all my networking code to be in its designated activity. Say i have a class called HttpMethods. In there one of the method will be getUserInfo. So that method will set up the JsonObjectRequest and add it to the RequestQueue. Once the function ends it will hit the onResult method of the listener in the JsonObjectRequest. After the repsonse is sent i now need to say. Update UI to look like this. In order to call the code to update the UI i have the method that makes the HTTP resquest in the activity and not in a seperate file

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to create a class extend Application like :

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    /**
     * Log or request TAG
     */
    public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";

    /**
     * Global request queue for Volley
     */
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    /**
     * A singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other places
     */
    private static ApplicationController sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize the singleton
        sInstance = this;
    }

    /**
     * @return ApplicationController singleton instance
     */
    public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
     */
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
        // created when it is accessed for the first time
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified
     * then it is used else Default TAG is used.
     * 
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

        VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue using the Default TAG.
     * 
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TAG);

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important
     * to specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
     * 
     * @param tag
     */
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

And for example you want in some Activity make a GET HTTP request is simple:

```
RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); // 'this' is Context
final String URL = "url";
    // pass second argument as "null" for GET requests
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null,
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try {
                       VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
               }
           });

    // add the request object to the queue to be executed
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```